# Unir count(*) de dos tablas en una Consulta SQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos consultas muy simples, en donde utilizo count en mis query para mostrar el numero de estudiantes y docentes de dos tablas diferentes.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) as total_estudiantes
 FROM form1_al WHERE id = $id and estado = 1");
 $resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
 $total = $resultado['total_estudiantes'];

 $sql_2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) as total_docentes
 FROM form_1_doc WHERE id = $id and estado = 1");
 $resultado_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_2);
 $total_2 = $resultado_2['total_docentes'];
```

Lo que necesito es unir ambas consultas, he probado utilizando la siguiente query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_estudiantes
FROM form1_al WHERE id = $id and estado = 1
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_docentes
FROM form_1_doc WHERE id = $id and estado = 1
```

Pero el resultado que muestra esta query, es en una sola columna.

```
total_estudiantes   
3
1
```

Lo que necesito es que muestre los resultados en dos columnas diferentes, de la siguiente manera:

```
total_estudiantes   total_docentes  
3                   1
```

Agradezco si alguien me puede orientar a resolver esto. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas haciendo dos queries y los quieres en uno solo, usa Select, con subQueries y boila,
Pero Jack no entiendo nada... ¿puedes explicarte mejor?

No!, mira el codigo, es mas facil de lo que puedo explicarme

```
SELECT (SELECT count(A.estado) 
          FROM form1_al A
         WHERE A.estado=1) TOTAL_ESTUDIANTE, 
        (SELECT count(B.estado)
          FROM form1_al B
          WHERE B.estado=1) TOTAL_PROFESOR
```

*Te lo dije, es mas facil de lo que dije xD*

Comment: Muchas gracias, te agradezco tu tiempo y respuesta. Tienes razón, no era compleja la solución, pero estaba un poco mareado.

Comment: pues no te preocupes, [tengo mala experiencia con SQL](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4354/28035) xD

Answer (score 2):

En el caso de que tengan como relación el id en este caso podrías intentar con un inner join.

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.*) as total_estudiantes, COUNT(t2.*) as total_docentes
FROM form1_al AS t1
INNER JOIN form_1_doc as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id = $id and t1.estado = 1 and t2.id = $id and t2.estado = 1
```

De lo contrario puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
SELECT total_estudiantes, total_docentes
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) as total_estudiantes, 
FROM form1_al AS t1,
       NULL AS total_docentes
FROM t1
  WHERE t1.id = $id and t1.estado = 1

UNION

SELECT NULL, 
       COUNT(*) as total_docentes, 
FROM form_1_doc as t2
  WHERE t2.id = $id and t2.estado = 1


) AS t;
```

Ahí puedes ir probando por si resulta alguna

Comment: la segunda parte del fragmento del codigo es muy util confirmo, pero para algo mas complejo

Comment: @JackNavaRow dale bro nunca están de más algunas líneas de código para futuros proyectos :D Saludos!!!